# Установить textSize в DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-studio, dialogfragment, android-dialog

В DialogFragment пытаюсь установить размер текста Message:

```
AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setCustomTitle(title)
                    .setMessage("text")
                    .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    })
                    .create();

    TextView textView = (TextView) builder.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    textView.setTextSize(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.title));
```

Но выдаёт 
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextSize(float)' on a null object reference`

Не понимаю что не так...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока вы не покажете диалог - его вьюшка не создается и поэтому вы получаете NPE, т.к. `textView = null`.

Т.е. инициализировать `textView` и устанавливать размер текста нужно после вызова метода `show` на диалоге.